# How can I download this file?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

This code works for most websites like google, youtube, facebook, etc but it doesn't work for some websites like technorati:

```
<?php
$favicon="http://technorati.com/favicon.ico";
$content = file_get_contents($favicon);
file_put_contents('favicon/icon.ico', $content);  

echo "<img src=\"http://localhost/test/favicon/icon.ico\" />";

?>
```

//output:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://technorati.com/favicon.ico)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/simple.php on
>   line 3
>
> http://localhost/test/favicon/icon.ico

How can I download the technorati's favicon ?

Comment: you could do it manually

Comment: Alp's solution is definitely the one with the least code. Less code == less headache.

Comment: Obviously, I need to do that with PHP :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at what happens when you issue the request, using Fiddler or Wireshark for example.

My guess is that the Technorati webserver is configured to deny automated requests, which it probably detects using the User Agent the crawler sends.

Using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) you can alter the user agent.

Answer (score 0):

Try to mimic browser and set user agent to something that technorati.com will like :)

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'Name of your bot');
```